# symfony: Form inside of another form gets author (article)

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-3.3

object `Article` has

```
 /**
 * @var Collection
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Photo", mappedBy="article", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $photos;
```

object `Photo` on its side has

```
/**
 * @var Article
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Article", inversedBy="photos")
 */
private $article;
```

I have a form of an object `Article`, which contains the object `Photo`' form as follows:

```
//article form building
->add('photos', CollectionType::class, [
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'allow_add' => true,
            'entry_type' => PhotoType::class,
            'entry_options' => [
                'label' => false,
            ]
        ])
```

in my `PhotoType` I have

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('image', ImageType::class, [
            'context' => 'photo',
        ])
        ->add('description')
        ->add('url')
...
```

But how do I set the `article` field in my `Photo` form? So that I could create photos with the defined `article_id` column in my table? Currently all created photos within this form have article_id NULL, in other words they don't have it set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your adder, you need to set the ID:

```
public function addPhoto(Photo $photo)
{
    if (!$this->photos->contains($photo)) {
        $this->photos[] = $photo;
        $photo->setDocument($this);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

and in your form, you need to set: `'by_reference' => false`, https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#by-reference

> Similarly, if you're using the CollectionType field where your underlying collection data is an object (like with Doctrine's ArrayCollection), then by_reference must be set to false if you need the adder and remover (e.g. addAuthor() and removeAuthor()) to be called.

Comment: thank you so much, it works. 'by_reference' => false was obligatory for me btw